# How can I produce the output of a carriage return in a \message?

Tags: tex-core, debugging

It's all in the title. How is it possible to output a carriage return in a `\message`. For debugging purposes, I need to get readable messages. The obvious doesn't work : `\message{A\cr B}` outputs `A\cr B` and `\message{A\\B}` produces an error like this

```
Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e
                        \relax \let \reserved@f
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say, but `\reserved@a` suggests that you are using latex in which case

```
\message{ab^^Jcde}
```

works although it is better to use latex constructs such as `\typeout` or `\PackageInfo`

In plain TeX the above `\message` will work if you set

```
\newlinechar=`\^^J
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the hint to use `\typeout`, that actually solves the whole problem.

Answer (score 5):

The `\message` primitive expands input in the same way as `\edef` and needs something which produces a 'raw' new line to get the desired effect. On the other hand, `\\` is a command to produce a line break in *typesetting*, so fails here (it is also not expandable, hence the odd error). You therefore need to insert a character equal to `\newlinechar`. In the LaTeX format this is `^^J`:

```
\message{a^^JB}
\stop
```

In formats where this is not set (such as plain), you'll also need to cover that

```
\begingroup
  \newlinechar=`^^J %
  \message{a^^JB}
\endgroup
\end
```